# How to Display Image after submitting webform in the confirmation message page

Tags: webforms

I have added field as file in webform so that we can add image in this file field. Now i want to display next page after submitting image file by using following code

[submission:values:image_file]

but I cant able to display the image in the confirmation page. how to display the image in the next page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of it you can directly try to add image in ***Confirmation message***.
You can find that under form settings in webform.

like this : `<img src="[submission:values:image_key]"/>`

Comment: there is no settings for displaying image file

Comment: [submission:values:image_key]  Also you can follow https://www.drupal.org/node/1515548